# Random telegraphic noise and Lorentzian noise power spectral density

Tags: power-spectral-density, time-frequency, time-series, random-process

[image]
[image]

Following the example of the Lorentzian noise power spectral density shown above ([ref](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5173283)), I would like to clarify the following:

1. In the first figure (labeled by (c)), May I please know why the constant levels of the noise PSD increase? Is the change in $\tau$ the only reason for this behavior?
2. In the second figure below it, the Lorentzian spectra show suppression and which is completely different from the behavior shown in the first figure. What is the physical significance of this behavior? I would like to understand what causes these two types of trend in Lorentzian generally, wherein in the first case, the corner frequency pushes inwards, and in the second case, the spectra shrink and corner frequency remains more or less the same.

It would be great to know your thoughts and explanation of these two behaviors!

Thanks a lot for your valuable time